# Servlet returns wrong response

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, response

I have just started servlets on this little project of mine so please be gentle.
I have a static HTML with some JS in the background that uses:

```
var xmlhttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttpRequest.readyState==4){
                if (xmlhttpRequest.status == 200){
                    var rString = xmlhttpRequest.responseText;
                    alert(rString);
                } 
            }
    }
```

and JS servlet call:

```
xmlhttpRequest.open("POST", "ServletBase", true);
xmlhttpRequest.send(this.someString);
```

Everything good; on the servlet, in the processResponse void I get the request String and pass that String to a java class call ACB:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
int requestLength = request.getContentLength();
PrintWriter pWriter = response.getWriter();
if(requestLength>1){
   String inputString = /* i get the string */;
   this.ACB.processPageCommand(inputString,pWriter);
}else{pWriter.write("NULL");}
```

Now, the ACB class is the working one who processes the inputString and communicates with an ArduinoBoard connected on COM3 and which implements `SerialPortEventListener`. After things happen, I use the pWriter in the ACB to write stuff back (sometimes a simple String, and sometimes a JSON object as a String):

```
this.pWriter.write(responseString);
```

The problem is that in the JS I receive the wrong data. For instance, I just set pin 32 HIGH in ACB and wanna write back a JSON `{"pin":"32","state":"1"}`. I get an empty response (the pin on the board is set right); if I set the same pin to LOW now, I should get `{"pin":"32","state":"0"}`, but now I get the first response: `{"pin":"32","state":"1"}` (the pin on the board is set right).

Right before I do the `this.pWriter.write(responseString);` I `System.out.println(responseString)` and the responseString is what it should be which means that the ArduinoBoard returned good data, and the processing of it went fine, but in the JS i get the 'previous data'.

I bet it is something trivial, but i can not get around it due to my lack of servlet thing knowledge. Also, sorry for a long post :D

Answer (score 0):

The browser is caching the responses. Set no-cache headers in the servlet that returns the data.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

That may solve it by itself on most browsers, but not on IE because IE will still try to cache responses received through Ajax.  To fix this you will need to add a parameter to your Ajax POST that is a timestamp or random number.  You just need to send this parameter to trick IE into working properly (by making it clear this is a unique request).  You don't have to read the parameter on the servlet end.

Comment: I did try setHeader and passing a unique number with each POST, but the same problem occurs. Now I belive it has something with the nature of my POST processing. Some POSTs do not require processing on the external hardware (the ArduinoBoard), and they return good, but there are some commands that the program waits on the external hardware to return a confirmation with a SerialPortEventListener. In the class I have the PrintWriter as a global variable, and only when the board returns some data do I write back to JS. Could it be that the servlet does not 'wait' that long?

Comment: Could it be that what happends is: the code creates a response String when the external hardware sends the data, and the next time i send a command, the servlet returns the previous response since the response String is created in the synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) of the SerialPortEventListener; and the PrintWriter is global in that class ..... something.

Comment: I can not upvote your suggestion since i do not have a high enough reputation, but i do thank you for getting me to think about caching :D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have a make-do solution for now (did not test is on all requests):

After I send a request that needs external hardware processing, I usually get an empty response since the PrintWriter.write(responseString) is in the `synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent)` of the `SerialPortEventListener`. On the JS side, I check the possible expected return data, and based on that I just immediately start sending empty requests (before issuing any meaningful requests) until i get a meaningful response - which is for now right the next response after the emtpy one.

I do not know if I should flag this as a answer, since I did not test it on all commands and request-response combinations, but in time .....